# How to use Asp.Net Core Identity in Multi-Tenant environment

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a working Asp.Net Core application with default Identity handling. Now I want to use it for multi domains. I extended ApplicationUser with DomainId.
How can I handle not just username / email to authenticate / register the user, but also the current DomainId?

It's not a problem to get the current DomainId when the user is registering, logging into the system, I have a working multi-tenant Asp.Net Core system. I have issue only with user management with DomainId.

Is there any setting for this? What should I override to get this funcionality? For example UserStore, UserManager?

I found some tutorial for old Asp.Net Identity for example this: https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Quick-and-Easy-ASPNET-Identity-Multitenancy
But I couldn't find any tutorial for the new Asp.Net Core Identity.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally I figured it out.
So first, I have to set user email to not unique. Sidenote: I'm using email for UserName also, I don't like to ask UserName from users:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
});
```

When a new user register himself, I'm merging current Domain Id to UserName, this helps users to register with same Email / UserName into the system through totally different domains.

Then I had to create my custom UserManager, where I'm overriding FindByEmail:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using MultiShop.Core.Repositories.User;
using MultiShop.Core.Tenant;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    public class MyShopUserManager<TUser> : UserManager<TUser>, IDisposable where TUser : class
{
    private readonly ITenantService tenantService;
    private readonly IUserRepository userRepository;

    public MyUserManager(IUserStore<TUser> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
        IPasswordHasher<TUser> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<TUser>> userValidators,
        IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<TUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
        IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<TUser>> logger,
        ITenantService tenantService, IUserRepository userRepository)
        : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
    {
        this.tenantService = tenantService;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public override async Task<TUser> FindByEmailAsync(string email)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        if (email == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(email));
        }

        var users = (await userRepository.GetAllAsync()).Where(u => u.Email == email);

        if (users == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (users.Count() == 1)
        {
            return await Store.FindByIdAsync(users.First().Id.ToString(), CancellationToken);
        }

        var currentDomain = tenantService.GetCurrentDomainAsync().Result;
        var user = users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.DomainId == currentDomain.Id);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return await Store.FindByIdAsync(user.Id.ToString(), CancellationToken);
    }
}
}
```

Be careful, because of multi-domains and generated UserNames, you should use userManager.FindByEmailAsync, instead of FindByNameAsync.

I had to create custom SignInManager for handling multi-domain users:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using MultiShop.Core.Tenant;
using MultiShop.Data.Entities;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
public class MySignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser>

{
    private readonly ITenantService tenantService;

    public MySignInManager(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
        IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
        ILogger<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>> logger, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes,
        ITenantService tenantService)
        : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemes)
    {
        this.tenantService = tenantService;
    }

    public override async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
    {
        var currentDomain = await tenantService.GetCurrentDomainAsync();
        return await base.PasswordSignInAsync($"{userName}{currentDomain.Id}", password, isPersistent, lockoutOnFailure);
    }
}
}
```

Finally I have to register my custom managers into Asp.Net Core Identity DI:

```
services
   .AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MultiShopDbContext>()
   .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
   //my custom managers for domain segmented users
   .AddUserManager<MyUserManager<ApplicationUser>>()
   .AddSignInManager<MySignInManager>();
```

That's it!

Comment: hi you should put up your soln on github, would help a lot of people and you will get votes

Comment: Identity says they don't support multi-tenancy. Does this work? Is there a working solution on GitHub? Looks fantastic.

Comment: @ChaimEliyah yes this is working, and all you need is what I wrote in the solution.

Comment: Well... and to override UserManager and RoleManager (if using roles) which isn't necessarily a simple thing.

Comment: As @transformer already wrote I would also love to see a working solution of it on github ;-)

Comment: Thanks for sharing @martonx, I could use your solution. Only thing I do not understand is why are you using some userrepository for?

Comment: @ParaJaco because of I have distributed caching in my userRepository, and lots of custom user related db layer logics.