# Unique UserName & Email per tenant

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, multi-tenant, asp.net-core-identity

I'm coding a multi-tenant app using `ASP.NET Core 2.1`.

I would like to override the default user-creation-related validation mechanism.

Currently I cannot create several users with the same `UserName`.

My `ApplicationUser` model has a field called `TenantID`.

What I'm trying to achieve: `UserName` & `EmailAddress` must be unique per tenant.

I've been googling a solution, but haven't found much info for `asp.net core` on this one.

Most of the results would only cover `Entity Framework` aspects, as if it's just a matter of [overriding](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1518) `OnModelCreating(...)` method. [Some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628850/microsoft-asp-net-identity-multiple-users-with-the-same-name) are related to NON-core edition of ASP.NET Identity.

I wonder if I should keep investigating `OnModelCreating` approach?

Or perhaps, there's something else that needs to be overridden around `Identity`?

Comment: OOTB Identity has no multi tenancy.  Although for an earlier version, [Quick and Easy ASP.NET Identity Multitenancy](https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Quick-and-Easy-ASPNET-Identity-Multitenancy) covers what would need to be changed.  Also see [How to use Asp.Net Core Identity in Multi-Tenant environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133171/).

Comment: The answer above was quite useful for me. Just be sure to check if there's no user with the same Username, Email and Tennant *besides* the user being validated, otherwise any edit on said user will break.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you need to disable the Identity's built-in validation mechanism:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    // disable the built-in validation
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
})
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Then, assuming you are registering users with the ASP.NET Core with Identity template, you could just do:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model); 
    }

    // check for duplicates
    bool combinationExists = await _context.Users
        .AnyAsync(x => x.UserName == model.UserName 
                 && x.Email == model.Email
                 && x.TenantId == model.TenantId);

    if (combinationExists)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    // create the user otherwise
}
```

---

If you don't want to do that kind of checking in the controller and would rather keep the Identity flow, you can create your own `IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>` pretty simply:

```
public class MultiTenantValidator : IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>
{
    public async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, ApplicationUser user)
    {
        bool combinationExists = await manager.Users
            .AnyAsync(x => x.UserName == user.UserName 
                        && x.Email == user.Email
                        && x.TenantId == user.TenantId);

        if (combinationExists)
        {
            return IdentityResult.Failed(new IdentityResult { Description = "The specified username and email are already registered in the given tentant" });
        }

        // here the default validator validates the username for valid characters,
        // let's just say all is good for now
        return IdentityResult.Success;
    }
}
```

And you would then tell Identity to use your validator:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddUserValidator<MultiTenantValidator>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

With this, when you call `UserManager.CreateAsync`, the validation will take place before creating the user.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Will investigate it soon.

Comment: @AlexHerman You are welcome. I have added a second answer just in case :)

Comment: I tried the second answer, but it gives me the error "unique index 'UserNameIndex'" on registering with the same email for another tenant, how can I make UserName not unique? also, you forgot to write await before "manager.Users.AnyAsync"