# How to use asp.net core 3.0 identity (Register & SignIn) for multiple UserName/Email with Different CompanyIDs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to use single database for multiple companies. So same User can register with their same email address as username with multiple companies. How to achieve this in asp.net core 3 using Identity?

Comment: Please post the code that you have attempted already.

Comment: Not sure you did understand what Identity Servers are. Identity Servers are there to validate the identity of the user, its unrelated to the company they work for (or if they work for a company at all). User can authorize with any email address he wants. The application (which has company related data) will redirect an unsigned user to the Identity Server, have him login, and be redirected back (with auth code or auth/identity token). This will tell your application: "The user is who he claims". Identity servers replace direct login/password with the application.

Comment: What the user can access still depends on how your application manages permission for that users  unique ID ("sub" claim jwt or when retrieved from userinfo endpoint)

Comment: For example : Register new user require 3 mandatory fields as follows: 1. CompanyId=1, email=abc@abc.com and password. 2. CompanyId=2, email=abc@abc.com and password. So on... But CompanyId=1 with email abc@abc.com will no more allowed to register. I found a similar post here but unable to work with it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133171/how-to-use-asp-net-core-identity-in-multi-tenant-environment.